# SQL query takes way too long

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This query takes about 52 seconds to complete.  It appears 82% of the time is spent in the table scan of the orders table.  It says the actual number of rows is over 8 million, so my only guess is that it is looping through this table and I'm not good enough with SQL to know why.

The orders table has 19700 rows currently.

```
SELECT a.DistID, a.BusCtrID, d.FName, d.LName, r.Description 
FROM funcGetDownline( 3 , 1) a
INNER JOIN Distributor d ON a.DistID = d.DistID
INNER JOIN Rank r ON d.RankID = r.RankID
INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.DistID = d.DistID
INNER JOIN orderlines ol ON ol.OrderID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY a.DistID, a.BusCtrID, d.FName, d.LName, r.Description'
```

funcGetDownline returns a single table returning 4,416 records.  If I execute the query just to the orders line it will return 15,361 rows which is should only be returning no more than 4,416.

If I execute the query to the orderlines it will return 20811 rows, again it should not be returning more than 4,416, less is ok, but not more.  It executes this in 1 seconds.

When I execute it down to the group row, it takes around 50 seconds to execute this query and returns 4,313 rows which seems to be the correct amount of rows.

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly here?

EDITED AGAIN:

```
SELECT tmp.distid, tmp.busctrid, tmp.volume, r.description, d.fname, d.lname, d.email
FROM
(
SELECT o.Distid, o.busctrid, SUM (ol.volume * ol.quantity) as Volume
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Orderlines ol
 ON ol.orderid = o.orderid
GROUP BY o.distid, o.busctrid
HAVING SUM (ol.volume * ol.quantity) BETWEEN 0 AND 3011
)tmp
INNER JOIN Distributor d
 ON d.distid = tmp.distid
INNER JOIN Rank r
 ON r.rankid = d.rankid
INNER JOIN FuncGetDownline(3,1) a
 ON a.distid = tmp.distid
 AND a.busctrid = tmp.busctrid
ORDER BY tmp.DistID, tmp.BusCtrID
```

The above query executes in 1 second or less, I'm nor why this is so much faster.  My Senior developer and I probably worked on this for about 60 minutes fine tuning it to be fast.

EDITED LONG LIST:

```
orders  PK_orders   Orderid
orders  PK_orders   Distid
orders  PK_orders   BusCtrID
orders  PK_orders   ShipAmt
orders  PK_orders   ShipDate
orders  PK_orders   ShipTrack
orders  PK_orders   TaxAmt
orders  PK_orders   invoicetype
orders  PK_orders   Notes
orders  PK_orders   PostAmount
orders  PK_orders   Status
orders  PK_orders   ShippingLine1
orders  PK_orders   ShippingLine2
orders  PK_orders   ShippingCity
orders  PK_orders   ShippingState
orders  PK_orders   ShippingCountry
orders  PK_orders   ShippingPostalCode
orders  PK_orders   EnteredBy
orders  PK_orders   PostFuturePeriod
orders  PK_orders   OrderDate
orders  PK_orders   MO_Ship
orders  PK_orders   ts
orders  PK_orders   ShippingPhone
orders  PK_orders   DatePaid
orders  PK_orders   PublicNotes
orders  PK_orders   LastUpdatedBy
orders  PK_orders   BonusDate
orders  PK_orders   TypeCode
orders  PK_orders   ShippingName
orders  PK_orders   GeoCode
orders  PK_orders   InOutCity
orders  PK_orders   TaxOption
orders  PK_orders   IsCredit
orders  PK_orders   TaxAmt2
orders  PK_orders   Aristo_Status
orders  PK_orders   WarehouseID
orders  PK_orders   ShipCost
orders  PK_orders   Weight
orders  PK_orders   Carrier
orders  PK_orders   Service
orders  PK_orders   OrderExported
orders  PK_orders   ShippingEmail
orders  PK_orders   CreditOrderID
orders  PK_orders   ShipMethod
orders  PK_orders   OrderID2
orders  PK_orders   PartyID
orders  PK_orders   ExportTimeStamp
orders  PK_orders   OrderIP
orders  PK_orders   PromoCode
orders  PK_orders   FirstOrder
Distributor Dist_PK DistID
Distributor Dist_PK Name
Distributor Dist_PK Status
Distributor Dist_PK Rank
Distributor Dist_PK OverRank
Distributor Dist_PK ORankDate
Distributor Dist_PK EnterDate
Distributor Dist_PK RenewalDate
Distributor Dist_PK Password
Distributor Dist_PK RankID
Distributor Dist_PK LName
Distributor Dist_PK FName
Distributor Dist_PK EnteredBy
Distributor Dist_PK MInitial
Distributor Dist_PK Email
Distributor Dist_PK RankDate
Distributor Dist_PK SSN
Distributor Dist_PK URL
Distributor Dist_PK HomePhone
Distributor Dist_PK WorkPhone
Distributor Dist_PK Fax
Distributor Dist_PK BillLine1
Distributor Dist_PK BillLine2
Distributor Dist_PK BillCity
Distributor Dist_PK BillState
Distributor Dist_PK BillPostalCode
Distributor Dist_PK BillCountry
Distributor Dist_PK ShipLine1
Distributor Dist_PK ShipLine2
Distributor Dist_PK ShipCity
Distributor Dist_PK ShipState
Distributor Dist_PK ShipPostalCode
Distributor Dist_PK ShipCountry
Distributor Dist_PK ts
Distributor Dist_PK FirstCycle
Distributor Dist_PK DistFlag1
Distributor Dist_PK DistFlag2
Distributor Dist_PK DistFlag3
Distributor Dist_PK DistFlag4
Distributor Dist_PK DistFlag5
Distributor Dist_PK DistFlag6
Distributor Dist_PK DistFlag7
Distributor Dist_PK HomePhoneExt
Distributor Dist_PK WorkPhoneExt
Distributor Dist_PK FaxExt
Distributor Dist_PK ExtraNumeric1
Distributor Dist_PK ExtraNumeric2
Distributor Dist_PK ExtraNumeric3
Distributor Dist_PK ExtraSring1
Distributor Dist_PK ExtraSring2
Distributor Dist_PK ExtraSring3
Distributor Dist_PK TaxExempt
Distributor Dist_PK txjr
Distributor Dist_PK GeoCode
Distributor Dist_PK InOutCity
Distributor Dist_PK DefaultWarehouse
Distributor Dist_PK TaxAsCustomer
Distributor Dist_PK CellPhone
Distributor Dist_PK PaidAsRank
Distributor Dist_PK TaxID
Distributor Dist_PK BankID
Distributor Dist_PK TrainerID
Distributor Dist_PK Statement
Distributor Dist_PK WebShowName
Distributor Dist_PK WebAddress
Distributor Dist_PK WebHomePhone
Distributor Dist_PK WebWorkPhone
Distributor Dist_PK WebFax
Distributor Dist_PK WebUrl
Distributor Dist_PK WebEmail
Distributor Dist_PK Photo
Distributor Dist_PK WebTemplate
Distributor Dist_PK HTMLEmail
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef1
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef2
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef3
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef4
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef5
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef6
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef7
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef8
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef9
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef10
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef11
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef12
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef13
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef14
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef15
Distributor Dist_PK EnableEcommerce
Distributor Dist_PK BirthDate
Distributor Dist_PK ModifiedBy
Distributor Dist_PK UserName
Distributor Dist_PK LastUpdateDate
Distributor Dist_PK ReceiveCompanyEmail
Distributor Dist_PK ReceiveUplineEmail
Distributor Dist_PK ReceiveUplineMessages
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef16
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef17
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef18
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef19
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef20
Distributor Dist_PK CreatedIP
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef21
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef22
Distributor Dist_PK UserDef23
Distributor Dist_PK OverrideMinChkAmt
Distributor Dist_PK ReceiveSponsorEmail
Distributor Dist_PK ReceiveDownlineActivityEmail
Distributor Dist_PK DefaultLanguage
Distributor Dist_PK DistID2
Distributor Dist_PK ImHandle
Distributor Dist_PK IMType
Distributor Dist_PK ReceivePersonallySponsoredActivityEmail
Distributor Dist_PK EnableWebsite
Distributor Dist_PK DistributorCenterExpireDate
Distributor Dist_PK WebsiteExpireDate
Distributor Dist_PK AutologinSessionID
Distributor Dist_PK RecoverPasswordKey
Distributor Dist_PK PCIUserID
Distributor Dist_PK TLPCountry
Distributor Dist_PK EncryptedSSN
Distributor Dist_PK EncryptedTaxID
Distributor Dist_PK AgreementAccepted
orderlines  PK_orderlines   OrderID
orderlines  PK_orderlines   OrderLineID
orderlines  PK_orderlines   ItemId
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Quantity
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Ship
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Amount
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Tax
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Weight
orderlines  PK_orderlines   StatusDate
orderlines  PK_orderlines   ShipDate
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Status
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Tracking1
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Tracking2
orderlines  PK_orderlines   RetailPrice
orderlines  PK_orderlines   WholesalePrice
orderlines  PK_orderlines   GroupItem
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Volume
orderlines  PK_orderlines   ts
orderlines  PK_orderlines   WarehouseID
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Notes
orderlines  PK_orderlines   ExtraCurrency1
orderlines  PK_orderlines   ExtraCurrency2
orderlines  PK_orderlines   ExtraCurrency3
orderlines  PK_orderlines   TaxRecID
orderlines  PK_orderlines   TrackingShipCo
orderlines  PK_orderlines   TaxRate
orderlines  PK_orderlines   MaxTaxAmt
orderlines  PK_orderlines   MaxOrderAmt
orderlines  PK_orderlines   CustomPrice
orderlines  PK_orderlines   DiscountPrice
orderlines  PK_orderlines   DiscountId
orderlines  PK_orderlines   DiscountDescription
orderlines  PK_orderlines   ShipCost
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Aristo_Status
orderlines  PK_orderlines   First_Time_Orderitem
orderlines  PK_orderlines   AttributeDetail
orderlines  PK_orderlines   Description
orderlines  PK_orderlines   BoxNumber
```

Comment: Is there an index on `o.DistID`  ?

Comment: @SQLMenace I'm not sure how to check if there is or is not.  This table houses our orders and can be updated several times a minute.  The orderlines table houses each item sold in the order.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server 2008?  2005?  MySQL?  etc etc.

Comment: @OCary I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Please see my edit and try the query I wrote so we can see where you are with your indexes.

Comment: @JamesWilson: you can always run `sp_helpindex` on your table to see what indices are defined: `EXEC sp_helpindex @objname = 'Orders'` should tell you if - and what - indices are defined on that table

Comment: @marc_s this returned the following: `PK_orders nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY Orderid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Are the columns in the GROUP BY clause indexed? If not then this will slow the query down.
- Are the "ID" columns marked as primary keys?  If not then they should be.  In many modern RDBMSs, columns marked as a primary key are automatically indexes
- Have you specified indexes on your foreign keys?  That is a.DistID, d.rankID, etc.  If not, then indexing your FK columns will speed up the query
- Using a function that returns a table may not be a good idea.  If this is being executed in SQL Server, then there is no way for the query optimizer to optimize that part of the query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indexes are probably the big one if you are seeing table scans.  It is also worth looking inside of your function to make sure that is effecient.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the number of records are going up is because Inner joins return a record for EACH match.

IE.

If you have 1 key in orders and 5 matching OrderID in Orderlines you will return 5 rows.

So you may have 4416 rows at one point which can easily explode to much higher numbers due to the joines and then due to the group by you get the number you expect back

EDIT

```
Try this query.  
  SELECT 
    T.Name as TableName, I.name as IndexName,s.name as IndexColumn
FROM 
    sys.indexes I 
INNER JOIN 
    Sys.tables t 
    ON 
        t.object_id = I.Object_ID 
inner join
    Sys.columns s
    on
        t.object_id = s.object_id
WHERE 
    index_id >= 1
    and
    t.type = 'U'
```

This should let us know where you are with the indexes.

Also can you post the execution plan generated?  If you run your query from the SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the query writing area and select include actual execution plan.

Comment: this returned 2409 rows.  No errors.  I'm not sure what data you need out of here, way to much to paste.

Comment: ok let's restrict the range.  Your database must have a huge number of indexes.  Try this.

`SELECT 
 T.Name as TableName, I.name as IndexName,s.name as IndexColumn
FROM 
 sys.indexes I 
INNER JOIN 
 Sys.tables t 
 ON 
  t.object_id = I.Object_ID 
inner join
 Sys.columns s
 on
  t.object_id = s.object_id
WHERE 
 index_id >= 1
 and
 t.type = 'U'
 and
 t.name in ('Distributor', 'Rank','Orders','OrderLines')`

Comment: this took it down to 211 rows. 50 of those being in orders and 122 of those being in distributor and the rest in orderlines.

Comment: Seeing those rows would be helpful.  The reason being, and I'm not sure your level of knowledge of how databases retrieve data, if you don't have an index and you want some data the database scans the tables to get the data you need.  What an index does is stores certain pieces of data in a datastructure, often a b-tree for quick identification.  It will have a pointer to the table with the rows containing the data you want.  This can result in Log N access to your data vs N access which is a tremendous boost.  So we needs to make sure you are properly using indexes when accessing the data

Comment: I would not describe a clustered index as not really index.

Comment: A clustered index is a specific type of index, the data in your table is ordered to match the index to speed up access if you could benefit from having the data ordered. Just for future reference.

Comment: @Blam You're right it was a terrible description.  Heh.  Replaced!

Comment: @Jordan added them to the OP.

Comment: Seems to me the 2nd query is so much faster because the limited use of group by.  In fact the 2 columns used in the group by are in the index `PK_orders` [probably sorted already] which makes for a quick operation.  In the original query you were grouping by information that was not in the index [ie fname, lname] and this is going to be very slow as grouping is a form of sorting and if you are sorting unindexed information [especially vs a sorted index or a clustered index] it is going to be _SLOW_

Answer (score 1):

first thing to check is that you have indexes on all the columns in the join clause.

second, your SQL indicates grouping, so the numbers of 20K may be correct BEFORE the grouping.

however, a group by clause normally indicates some type of math on the group, such as a sum() function, which i do not see in your sql.  you could try a distinct instead of group by:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.DistID, a.BusCtrID, d.FName, d.LName, r.Description 
 FROM funcGetDownline( 3 , 1) a INNER JOIN Distributor d ON a.DistID =
 d.DistID INNER JOIN Rank r ON d.RankID = r.RankID INNER JOIN Orders o
 ON o.DistID = d.DistID INNER JOIN orderlines ol ON ol.OrderID =
 o.OrderID
```

Comment: This does allow me to get rid of the group by which I like, but the time it takes to execute the query is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of this, but it appears that you don't need data from orders or orderlines but just to know that they exist for this query, so ...

```
SELECT a.DistID, a.BusCtrID, d.FName, d.LName, r.Description  
FROM funcGetDownline( 3 , 1) a 
INNER JOIN Distributor d ON a.DistID = d.DistID 
INNER JOIN Rank r ON d.RankID = r.RankID 
where exists (select o.distid from  Orders o 
INNER JOIN orderlines ol ON ol.OrderID = o.OrderID 
where o.DistID = d.DistID )
```

Comment: I think you mean exists ( select o.DistID